# Import Jest into regular file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

Is it possible to import Jest into a file that will not be run as a test and does not contain test cases (e.g. a helper module for tests)?

Comment: why would you want to do that ? like helpers are meant to setup data  used by the code which is to be tested

Comment: That's what I want to do. But I need mock functions that are always the same, so it makes sense to put them into an external module for reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. With Jest as a dev dependency, `jest` is available in a test environment. You can create mocked Jest functions in a helper file and import them into your test.

Test file:

```
import { exampleFunc } from '../helper';

test('exampleFunc/0', () => {
  console.log(exampleFunc());
});
```

Helper file:

```
export const exampleFunc = jest.fn().mockReturnValue('mocked return');
```

Test run:

```
$ jest
 PASS  __tests__/index.test.ts
  ✓ exampleFunc/0 (12ms)

  console.log __tests__/index.test.ts:4
    mocked return
```